# Container can't connect to the internet

Tags: docker, networking

I'm trying to update packages from an ubuntu container; however, updating fails and I've noticed I can't connect anywhere, am able to lookup dns names thought.

I'm using nicolaka/netshoot container in order to test network.

I've used "tcpdump" command in order to trace any error related to messages being sent, and testing with ping from the container results in the following error "ICMP time exceeded in-transit".

tcpdump in host interface:

```
16:18:25.257270 IP 172.217.192.100 > nicolas: ICMP echo reply, id 33, seq 3, length 64
16:18:25.257314 IP nicolas > 172.217.192.100: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 92
16:18:26.237575 IP nicolas > 172.217.192.100: ICMP echo request, id 33, seq 4, length 64
16:18:26.286692 IP 172.217.192.100 > nicolas: ICMP echo reply, id 33, seq 4, length 64
16:18:26.286757 IP nicolas > 172.217.192.100: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 92
16:18:27.261770 IP nicolas > 172.217.192.100: ICMP echo request, id 33, seq 5, length 64
16:18:27.302193 IP 172.217.192.100 > nicolas: ICMP echo reply, id 33, seq 5, length 64
16:18:27.302241 IP nicolas > 172.217.192.100: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 92
16:18:28.285631 IP nicolas > 172.217.192.100: ICMP echo request, id 33, seq 6, length 64
16:18:28.329531 IP 172.217.192.100 > nicolas: ICMP echo reply, id 33, seq 6, length 64
16:18:28.329596 IP nicolas > 172.217.192.100: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 92
16:18:29.309767 IP nicolas > 172.217.192.100: ICMP echo request, id 33, seq 7, length 64
16:18:29.353202 IP 172.217.192.100 > nicolas: ICMP echo reply, id 33, seq 7, length 64
16:18:29.353272 IP nicolas > 172.217.192.100: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 92
```

Also I'm not sure if my iptables are as expected for docker containers to get internet connection.

iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll close this question as I have found the problem is with my ISP, which by using double NAT (ISP NAT + Docker NAT) is blocking connections from my containers.

Answer (score 0):

Whats is your result of ping 8.8.8.8 in container?
or whats is your commend when you want to run container.

Comment: Ping from a container fails with 100% loss, this is an example of a container command I'm running.

docker run -it nicolaka/netshoot

Comment: I think you can remove docker from your computer and install it again for install docker you can 
`$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh` 
`$ chmod +x get-docker.sh `
`$sudo ./get-docker.sh`